Есть карта с яндекса с фильтрами , как по клику на кнопку приблежать к определнной метке?
Есть фильтрация меток,но при клике на кнопку не маштабируется к этой метке , как это реализовать?


const categoriesData = {
  category1: [{
      lat: 53.442131071027305,
      lon: 58.99983849999995,
      name: 'Северный переход, 20а1',
      caption: 'Северный переход, 20а',
    },
  ],
  category2: [{
      lat: 53.426321310730245,
      lon: 58.9609671588954,
      name: 'ул. Советская, 20а',
      caption: 'ул. Советская, 20а'
    },
  ],
  category3: [{
      lat: 53.35935432593927,
      lon: 59.007853228836,
      name: 'ул. Коробова, 20',
      caption: 'ул. Коробова, 20'
    },
  ],
};

const init = () => {
  const map = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID-1', {
    center: [53.442131071027305,58.99983849999995],
    zoom: 14,
  });

  let activeCategory = "category1";

  const showCategory = (category) => {
    map.geoObjects.removeAll();

    categoriesData[category].forEach((item) => {
      const placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([item.lat, item.lon], {
        iconColor: '#1d79d3',
        hintContent: item.name,
        balloonContent: item.name,
        iconCaption: item.caption,
      });
      
      map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
    });

    activeCategory = category;
  }

  const categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.category-button');
  categoryButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const category = e.currentTarget.dataset.category;
      showCategory(category);
    });
  });

  showCategory(activeCategory);
};

ymaps.ready(init);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Создаём контейнер для карты -->
  <div class="container">
  <div class="container__wrapper">
          <button class=" category-button" data-category="category1">
            <p>Северный переход, 20а</p>
          </button>
          <button class=" category-button" data-category="category2">
            <p>ул. Советская, 20а</p>
          </button>
          <button class=" category-button" data-category="category3">
            <p>ул. Коробова, 20</p>
          </button>
  </div>


  <div id="YMapsID-1" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
  </div>         




Пожалуйста, отправьте функционирующий пример, который вы составили в jsbin.com или codepen.io, или ссылку на страницу, где мы можем воспроизвести эту ситуацию.

Выложила
Там когда кликаешь на кноки не меняется маштаб и метки не видно, видно только тогда, когда отдалишь карту, но нужно чтобы маштабировалось по клику , заранее спасибо

@YaSupport здесь и так есть такие возможности, просто вставлено криво было. Не нужно на сторонние сервисы ничего переносить.

Вы можете обрабатывать нажатие на div-элемент и центрировать карту на метке и менять масштабирование после клика с помощью Map.setCenter().

Спасибо , проблема решилась
